# The inverse of AND operation (multiplication) in binary

Tags: inverse, binary

I want to change the below equation into an equation for x (x=~~).

> a = (b⨁x)⋅c⨁d

where (a, b, c, d, x)∈{0, 1} and ⨁, · means XOR (addition) operation and AND (multiplication) operation, respectively.

The above equation can be changed as follows

> a⨁d = (b⨁x)⋅c

And then, I'm not sure how to compute "c" in the above equation.